# Unable to open swagger-ui.html using springdoc-openapi-ui

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am using (Spring MVC 4.3.11.RELEASE), (spring-boot, spring-boot-autoconfigure 1.5.7.RELEASE).
In which trying to integrate springdoc-openapi-ui 1.5.9

- On the [API-JSON DOC](http://localhost:8080/context-path/v3/api-docs) it is returning a proper JSON formatted document.
  [image]
- When am trying to hit [swagger-ui.html](http://localhost:8080/context-path/swagger-ui.html) then it says 404 but the URL is getting changed to http://localhost:8080/context-path/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/context-path/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
  [image]
- On [Swagger-config](http://localhost:8080/context-path/v3/api-docs/swagger-config) URL
  [image]
- I have referred to these
  [How to Integrate Open API 3 with Spring project (not Spring Boot)?](https://springdoc.org/faq.html)
  The last part of the above link is configured like the below ss.
  [image]

**Can anyone help me to fix the swagger-ui?**

Comment: Are you using Spring Web Mvc (`@EnableWebMvc`)?

Comment: @Dickson I am using XML based configuration(<mvc:annotation-driven />) instead of annotations